# Find area of Pentagram : Regular Pentagon if $AP : PQ = m:1$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

While I was doing an Olympiad geometry sum in Sri Lanka I found this question

A pentagram is a regular pentagon with its sides extended to their point of intersection. In the
pentagram ABCDE shown below PQRST is a regular pentagon.

If AP:PQ = m:1 then what is the ratio ,the area of the pentagram : the area of the pentagon ?

There are 5 answers:-

[image: Answers]

[image: Image of the question]

The above is the image of the question

My Attempt:-

[image: My attempt]

I drew SP, and SQ so I got congruent $\triangle PTS$ and $\triangle SQR$

And also I found that $\triangle ATP$,$\triangle BPQ$,$\triangle CQR$,$\triangle DSR$,$\triangle ETS$,$\triangle SPQ$ are congruent

And also I drew vertical heights h in $\triangle SRQ$ and H in $\triangle SPQ$

Then I took AP as $lm$ and PQ as $l$

I find the value of H and h from $l$ and $m$ but the simplifying of the answer is very hard to find the ratio

So anyone could help me with this question

Thank you

Comment: *Hint*: $[PAT]:[QPT]=AP:PQ=m:1$, so express every area in the diagram as in the form of $(am+b)[QPT]$, some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Indeed, generally speaking, thinking in terms of (ratio of) areas is often rewarding in this type of questions. It is rather often connected with the use of barycentric coordinates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @user10354138 in comments, this is the most elegant answer.

[image: answer]

Alternatively you can use the following method (which is a little bit lengthy).

[image]

Let $\angle PQS$ be $\theta$. (I will use $\text p$ to imply pentagon and $\triangle$ to represent all triangles those are congruent with $\triangle BPQ$). So we get $$\triangle=\frac 12\cdot m\cdot \sin \theta\implies \sin\theta=\frac{2\triangle}{m}$$
Remove $\triangle QRS$ from its position and paste it on $\triangle BFQ$. Now $BTSF$ is a parallelogram and its area is equal to $\text{pentagon}+\triangle$.$$\text p+\triangle=(m+1)\cdot 1 \cdot\sin\theta$$ $$\text p+\triangle=(m+1)\cdot \frac{2\triangle}{m}$$ $$\implies\text p=\frac{(m+2)\triangle}{m}$$

Now what we have to calculate is $$\frac{\text{pentagram}}{\text{pentagon}}=\frac {\text p+5\triangle}{\text p}$$ Can you do that?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Solution figure]

Let the area of $\triangle APT$ be $A$ i.e. $[APT]=A$. Notice that $\triangle APT$ and $\triangle PQT$ have the same height. So $$[APT]:[PQT]=m:1\implies [PQT]=\frac{[APT]}{m}=\frac Am.$$ Now notice that $\triangle PQT$ and $\triangle RTS$ are congruent (why?). Also $\triangle QRT$ and $\triangle QRC$ are congruent because $\angle TQR=\angle TRQ=\angle CQR=\angle CRQ=72^\circ$ and they have the same side $QR$. In other words, they have the same area.

Now $[PAT]=[BPQ]=[QRC]=[RSD]=[SET]=A$ (by symmetry) and $[PQT]=[RTS]=\frac Am$. So area of the pentagon is $[QTR]+2[PQT]=A+\frac{2A}m$ and area of the pentagram is $A+\frac{2A}m+5A=6A+\frac{2A}m$.

Hence, $\text{area of the pentagram:area of pentagon}=6A+\frac{2A}m:A+\frac{2A}m=6m+2:m+2.$